# jQuery validation and check all together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make a jquery validation, problem is here that this part from code first(first click on button) check selectbox and second(second click on button) fields. how can it fix as that check all together with one click on button?

**Exampel(see full code):** http://jsfiddle.net/JfPaN/

```
$('.submit').submit(function () {
    if (required_selectbox() == false || required_valid() == false) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a jQuery validate plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by [Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) on this line expression :

```
required_selectbox() == false || required_valid() == false
```

Javascript will not execute `required_valid()` if `required_selectbox()` returns false, since it already knows the result of the boolean expression as soon as the left side is true.

Here is one solution to your problem:

```
$('.submit').submit(function(){
    var passed = required_selectbox();
    passed = required_valid() && passed;
    if(!passed)
        return false;
});
```